# GIF stopped animate when upload file

Tags: php, image, upload, gif

i have problem when i upload image which is .gif they stopped animating.

What should i change to fix this problem. I try a lost thing to delete and edit but none of these fixing wasn't worked.

There is code:

```
class ImageResize {
private $generate_image_file;
private $generate_thumbnails;
private $image_max_size;
private $thumbnail_size;
private $thumbnail_prefix;
private $destination_dir;
private $thumbnail_destination_dir;
private $save_dir;
private $quality;
private $random_file_name;
private $config;
private $file_count;
private $image_width;
private $image_height;
private $image_type;
private $image_size_info;
private $image_res;
private $image_scale;
private $new_width;
private $new_height;
private $new_canvas;
private $new_file_name;
private $curr_tmp_name;
private $x_offset; 
private $y_offset;
private $resized_response;
private $thumb_response;
private $unique_rnd_name;
public $response;

function __construct($config) { 
        //set local vars
        $this->generate_image_file = $config["generate_image_file"];
        $this->generate_thumbnails = $config["generate_thumbnails"];
        $this->image_max_size = $config["image_max_size"];
        $this->thumbnail_size = $config["thumbnail_size"];
        $this->thumbnail_prefix = $config["thumbnail_prefix"];
        $this->destination_dir = $config["destination_folder"];
        $this->thumbnail_destination_dir = $config["thumbnail_destination_folder"];
        $this->random_file_name = $config["random_file_name"];
        $this->quality = $config["quality"];
        $this->file_data = $config["file_data"];
        $this->file_count = count($this->file_data['name']);
}

//resize function
public function resize(){
    if($this->generate_image_file){
        $this->response["images"] = $this->resize_it();
    }
    if($this->generate_thumbnails){
        $this->response["thumbs"] = $this->thumbnail_it();
    }
    return $this->response;
}

//proportionally resize image
private function resize_it(){
    if($this->file_count > 0){
        if(!is_array($this->file_data['name'])){
            throw new Exception('HTML file input field must be in array format!');
        }
        for ($x = 0; $x < $this->file_count; $x++){

            if ($this->file_data['error'][$x] > 0) { 
                $this->upload_error_no = $this->file_data['error'][$x];
                throw new Exception($this->get_upload_error()); 
            }   

            if(is_uploaded_file($this->file_data['tmp_name'][$x])){

                $this->curr_tmp_name = $this->file_data['tmp_name'][$x];
                $this->get_image_info();

                //create unique file name
                if($this->random_file_name){ 
                    $this->new_file_name = uniqid().$this->get_extension();
                    $this->unique_rnd_name[$x] = $this->new_file_name;
                }else{
                    $this->new_file_name = $this->file_data['name'][$x];
                }

                $this->curr_tmp_name = $this->file_data['tmp_name'][$x];
                $this->image_res = $this->get_image_resource();
                $this->save_dir = $this->destination_dir;                       
                //do not resize if image is smaller than max size
                if($this->image_width <= $this->image_max_size || $this->image_height <= $this->image_max_size){                    
                    $this->new_width    = $this->image_width;
                    $this->new_height   =  $this->image_height;                     
                    if($this->image_resampling()){
                        $this->resized_response[] = $this->save_image();
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->image_scale  = min($this->image_max_size/$this->image_width, $this->image_max_size/$this->image_height);
                    $this->new_width    = ceil($this->image_scale * $this->image_width);
                    $this->new_height   = ceil($this->image_scale * $this->image_height);   

                    if($this->image_resampling()){
                        $this->resized_response[] = $this->save_image();
                    }
                }
                imagedestroy($this->image_res);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->resized_response;
}

//generate cropped and resized thumbnails
private function thumbnail_it(){
    if($this->file_count > 0){
        if(!is_array($this->file_data['name'])){
            throw new Exception('HTML file input field must be in array format!');
        }
        for ($x = 0; $x < $this->file_count; $x++){

            if ($this->file_data['error'][$x] > 0) { 
                $this->upload_error_no = $this->file_data['error'][$x];
                throw new Exception($this->get_upload_error()); 
            }   

            if(is_uploaded_file($this->file_data['tmp_name'][$x])){
                $this->curr_tmp_name = $this->file_data['tmp_name'][$x];
                $this->get_image_info();

                if($this->random_file_name && !empty($this->unique_rnd_name)){
                    $this->new_file_name = $this->thumbnail_prefix.$this->unique_rnd_name[$x];
                }else if($this->random_file_name){
                    $this->new_file_name = $this->thumbnail_prefix.uniqid().$this->get_extension();
                }else{
                    $this->new_file_name = $this->thumbnail_prefix.$this->file_data['name'][$x];
                }

                $this->image_res = $this->get_image_resource();

                $this->new_width = $this->thumbnail_size;
                $this->new_height = $this->thumbnail_size;
                $this->save_dir = $this->thumbnail_destination_dir; 


                $this->y_offset = 0; $this->x_offset = 0;
                if($this->image_width > $this->image_height){
                    $this->x_offset = ($this->image_width - $this->image_height) / 2;
                    $this->image_width = $this->image_height  = $this->image_width - ($this->x_offset * 2);
                }else{
                    $this->y_offset = ($this->image_height - $this->image_width) / 2;
                    $this->image_width = $this->image_height  = $this->image_height - ($this->y_offset * 2);
                }

                if($this->image_resampling()){
                    $this->thumb_response[] = $this->save_image();
                }
                imagedestroy($this->image_res);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->thumb_response;
}

//save image to destination
private function save_image(){
    if(!file_exists($this->save_dir)){ //try and create folder if none exist
        if(!mkdir($this->save_dir, 0755, true)){
            throw new Exception($this->save_dir . ' - directory doesn\'t exist!');
        }
    }

    switch($this->image_type){//determine mime type
        case 'image/png': 
            imagepng($this->new_canvas, $this->save_dir.$this->new_file_name); imagedestroy($this->new_canvas); return $this->new_file_name; 
            break;
        case 'image/gif': 
            imagegif($this->new_canvas, $this->save_dir.$this->new_file_name); imagedestroy($this->new_canvas); return $this->new_file_name; 
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg': 
            imagejpeg($this->new_canvas, $this->save_dir.$this->new_file_name, $this->quality); imagedestroy($this->new_canvas); return $this->new_file_name; 
            break;
        default: 
            imagedestroy($this->new_canvas);
            return false;
    }
}

//get image info
private function get_image_info(){
    $this->image_size_info  = getimagesize($this->curr_tmp_name);
    if($this->image_size_info){
        $this->image_width      = $this->image_size_info[0]; //image width
        $this->image_height     = $this->image_size_info[1]; //image height
        $this->image_type       = $this->image_size_info['mime']; //image type
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Make sure Image file is valid image!");
    }
}   

//image resample
private function image_resampling(){
    $this->new_canvas   = imagecreatetruecolor($this->new_width, $this->new_height);
    if(imagecopyresampled($this->new_canvas, $this->image_res, 0, 0, $this->x_offset, $this->y_offset, $this->new_width, $this->new_height, $this->image_width, $this->image_height)){
        return true;
    }   
}

//create image resource
private function get_image_resource(){
    switch($this->image_type){
        case 'image/png':
            return imagecreatefrompng($this->curr_tmp_name); 
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            return imagecreatefromgif($this->curr_tmp_name); 
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
            return imagecreatefromjpeg($this->curr_tmp_name); 
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

private function get_extension(){
       if(empty($this->image_type)) return false;
       switch($this->image_type)
       {
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';
           default: return false;
       }
   }

private function get_upload_error(){
    switch($this->upload_error_no){
        case 1 : return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
        case 2 : return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.';
        case 3 : return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
        case 4 : return 'No file was uploaded.';
        case 5 : return 'Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3';
        case 6 : return 'Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0';
    }
}}
```

I have all this private variable set and i just want regular ajax image upload. With random name and accepted only jpg, gif and png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if keeping a GIF animation doesn't work in default PHP `imagegif()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php#113155

You can try running GD and processing that way: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php ImageMagick should also support this.